# Deserializing such that a field is an empty list rather than null

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

If I have a class like this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "", Namespace = "")]
public class MyDataObject
{
    [DataMember(Name = "NeverNull")]
    public IList<int> MyInts { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way I can make MyInts field a non-null empty list when the following string is deserialized?

```
string serialized = @"{""NeverNull"":null}";

MyDataObject myDataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyDataObject>(serialized);
```

I’m using Newtonsoft.Json

The reason I ask is that I have a fairly complicated json request to parse, it contains nests of lists of objects and I'd like the deserialization code to create these object so I can avoid lots of null checks:

```
if (foo.bar != null)
{
    foreach (var bar in foo.bar)
    {
        if (bar.baz != null)
        {
            foreach (var baz in bar.baz)
            {
                ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps add a post-serialization callback that checks this at the end of deserialization?

```
[DataContract(Name = "", Namespace = "")]
public class MyDataObject
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        if (MyInts == null) MyInts = new List<int>();
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "NeverNull")]
    public IList<int> MyInts { get; set; }
}
```

Note also that `JsonConvert` (unlike `DataContractSerializer`) executes the default constructor, so *usually* you could also have just added a default constructor:

```
    public MyDataObject()
    {
        MyInts = new List<int>();
    }
```

however, in this case the **explict** `"NeverNull":null` changes it back to `null` during deserialization, hence why I've used a callback above instead.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of `IList<int>`with `new int[0]` will help you out!
Its the solution that gives me the best results.

Comment: As Marc Gravell mentioned, the empty collection is overwritten by explicit null in json. -1